# regex always evaluating true in PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm trying to check for a positive or negative float or integer value in PHP but I cannot figure out why my regular expression is always evaluating true.

Here's the code:

```
if ( preg_match('/-?[\d]*\.?[\d]*/',   "1.57a") ) {
  echo "OK: matches";
} else {
  echo "Bad: doesn't match";
  exit();
}
```

I've tested the regexp pattern in a couple of testers and it matches and mismatches as I need, but the above code /always/ returns 1.

I'm guessing it's something really obvious but I just can't find it.

Comment: `*` mean **zero** or more

Comment: All your placeholders are optionalized `?`, so the regex might even match an empty string.

Comment: @jakegould can you explain why it matches 1.57a... It's not supposed to and the tested I'm using returns that as a mismatch. (The tester is an android app).

Comment: @mario good point, I'll change the first [\d]* to [\d]+ that should force at least one digit shouldn't it?

Comment: Your question does not explain if you want to match a number *anywhere* or if the string *at whole* must match (then anchor with `^` and `$`).

Comment: How's that mad person giving downvote for everyone ?!

Comment: Does the tester you're using understand the leading and trailing slash characters in your regex?  It might not.

Comment: @richiehindle the slashes confuse the tester - it just wants the pattern so that's what I was using - but it fails to match when the pattern actually dies match as per Sam and cHau's explanations in their answers. The clincher is binding the start and end of the string and pattern and making the first digit a 'one or more' rather than a 'zero or more'.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are a couple issues with your expression, but I think you are looking for:

```
/^-?\d*(?:\.\d+)?$/
```

[**Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/xF2nT7)

---

The big thing here is that you want to use the anchors `^` and `$` to bind your match to the beginning and end of the string.  Otherwise, `1.57a` will match since `1.57` is a match (even though `a` makes the number invalid).

I also grouped the `.` with 1+ digits and made the whole group optional (so `1.` doesn't match, but `1.57` does).

Comment: Why the -1s?  If this is OP downvoting everyone's posts, care to elaborate on why these don't work?

Comment: Not me down voting. I don't understand why all the down votes either. Seems like perfectly valid discussion to me...

Comment: I guess someone just had a bad day and is spreading their downvotes..did you get things working @FatMonk, or do you need more help?

Comment: Your solution is perfect. And the explanation about why it's matching got me on track... Time to ditch that android app as its very misleading.

Comment: [Regex101](http://regex101.com/) is my favorite GUI tool for writing/testing expressions. Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 5):

Let's take a look at your regex.

`-?[\d]*\.?[\d]*` matches

- an *optional* dash, followed by
- zero or more (read: *optional*) digits, then
- an *optional* dot, and then
- zero or more (again, *optional*) digits.

Since every part is optional, even an empty string will match.  And since you haven't anchored the pattern, it'll successfully match zero chars anywhere in the string.

If you want the expression to fail on everything but numbers, then you need to do two things:

1. **Anchor the pattern.** Use `^` and `$` at the beginning and end of the pattern, respectively.  This will keep strings from matching if they have the wrong characters in the wrong places.
2. **Make one of the parts required.**  At least one part of your pattern needs to match once-or-more; otherwise, it'll match even an empty string.

Note that either one of these alone is not quite enough.  Anchoring the pattern won't exclude empty strings, and making a part required won't keep your pattern from matching things like `whatever0.5`.  You need to do both, unless you're *trying* to match any numeric-looking part of your string.  (Even then, you might want to look at using `\b` and/or lookaheads/lookbehinds to help ensure you're not starting or ending in wacky places like in the middle of a word.)